# What does `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.add0n.node'` mean in a web extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I am writing a web extension that needs to call pandoc. I have been looking at [YouTube Downloader](https://github.com/feller-prj/extractor-project) as an example of how to call an external program. I have looked at the Web Extension documentation for how to use the [nativeMessage system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging#App_manifest) and it insists on needing a [Application manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests#Manifest_location) to identify the external program to the web browser and the extension. I can not find where YouTube Downloader has its application manifest; appearing not to be using one. Instead it initiated a connection to FFMPEG (audio video program that handles muxing together the YouTube video from the host system) by the way of this section of code:

```js
ffmpeg.convert = function(command, args, dictionary) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    args = args.split(/\s/).map(s => {
      Object.keys(dictionary).forEach(key => s = s.replace(key, dictionary[key]));
      return s;
    });
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.add0n.node', {
      cmd: 'exec',
      kill: true,
      command,
      arguments: args
    }, obj => {
      if (!obj || obj.error || (obj.code && obj.code !== 0)) {
        console.error(obj);
        reject(new Error(obj ? obj.error || obj.stderr || obj.stdout : 'error_12'));
      }
      else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

FFMPEG is already installed on my system, so there is not problem for it to be called. But I cannot find where FFMPEG's application manifest would be stored. I don't even see the extension calling for FFMPEG in the nativeMessage system, instead calling for `'com.add0n.node'`. I have tried mimicking this for own extension and I get an error message saying that `'com.add0n.node'` is unknown.

Setting up the application manifest for my own system is not an issue. But I was hoping to share my web extension and not expect the end users need to understand how to administer their systems to add an application manifest to make pandoc known to the web browser. I would want my users to need to do is install my web extension and pandoc and not have to understand how to change their configuration files regrading the web browser. I'm not sure if there is a standard way of adding application manifests when people install web extensions that rely on them. (It would be unreasonable to expect me to repackage pandoc to accommodate the needs of my web extension.) I'm not sure how YouTube Downloader gets away with using `'com.add0n.node'`?

Comment: As the documentation says that external additional program's manifest must be separately registered. There is no other way. Extensions can't call *arbitrary* programs.

Comment: Googling for "com.add0n.node" I see it's a standalone utility: [link](https://github.com/andy-portmen/native-client).

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, that does actually answer my question. Now I just have to make a script similar to the one used to install native client to install the system files for my extension. Thanks.